# How to use nested forms in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a question on rails3 nested_form.
 These are my two models:

```
class User
   belongs_to :shop
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :shop
end

class Shop
  has_many :users
end
```

In my register view(i am using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)):

```
form_for(resourse,:url => registration(resource_name)) do  |f|
   =f.fields_for :shop do |s|
     =s.text_fields :name
```

but i get nothing for this form. What should i do?

Comment: Are you using simple_form or formtastic?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add some objects first to it. Use build method on model in controller.

Example:

```
@shop = Shop.new
3.times { @shop.users.build }
```

More informations at [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1). AJAX is used in [second part](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) of this video.